# divs inside a tag goes to new line

Tags: html, css

Im trying to align my a-tags side by side, but for some reason the divs inside the a-tag goes to the next line?

How can I align my three menu lines side by side with the others? `display: inline-block;` didn't work for me?

What I'm trying to create is something like this image:

[image: ![enter image description here]

But what do I miss to get the menu on the same line?

```css
.logo-style {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 39px;
    /* identical to box height */
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: #4C5BA0;
}

/*
    Navigation bar three lines menu

/*
 Navigation
*/

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none !important;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.topnav button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav a {
    color: brown;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    color: black;
}


*/

.line-one {
    width: 30px;
}

.line-one {
    width: 30px;
}

.line-one {
    width: 30px;
}

.menu div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: brown;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.menu {
    width: 30px;
}

.menu:hover div {
    width: 30px;
    background-color: black;
}

.right-nav {}

.left-nav {}
```

```html
<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/site.scss">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/toggletheme.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="topnav">
            <div class="left-nav">
                <a href="#news"><p class="logo-style">Web title</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="right-nav">
                <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="#archives">Archives</a>
                <a href="#coverage">Coverage</a>
                <a href="#menu" class="menu">
                    <div class="line-one"></div>
                    <div class="line-two"></div>
                    <div class="line-three"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use `display: flex;` to `.right-nav` class. And center elements properly `align-items: center`; `justify-content: center;`
Now everything works fine:-) Best regards!

```
 .right-nav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```css
.logo-style {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 39px;
  /* identical to box height */
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #4c5ba0;
}

/*
    Navigation bar three lines menu

/*
 Navigation
*/

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav a {
  color: brown;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  color: black;
}

.right-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


*/ .line-one {
  width: 30px;
}

.line-one {
  width: 30px;
}

.line-one {
  width: 30px;
}

.menu div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: brown;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.menu {
  width: 30px;
}

.menu:hover div {
  width: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="topnav">
    <div class="left-nav">
      <a href="#news">
        <p class="logo-style">Web title</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-nav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#archives">Archives</a>
      <a href="#coverage">Coverage</a>
      <a href="#menu" class="menu">
        <div class="line-one"></div>
        <div class="line-two"></div>
        <div class="line-three"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please read [answer]. **code only** answers are considered low-quality. Without sufficient explaination it is hard to understand what you did or how you solve the issue. As such it is also hard to reproduce and your answer is **not helpfull**!

Comment: Well sorry i have already corrected, forgive, i am brand new ;-)

Comment: This works, but if i scale the page down to 200px in width then there isn't any vertical scroll bar i can use? how can i click somthing i cant see then? :)

Comment: The question is, why do you need such a small width (200px) ??
I think less like 320px doesn't make sense. In smaller screens you will have to use Media queries and adjust navigation accordingly, but that's a good topic for a separate question ;-)
Best regards and Thank you :-P

Answer (score 5):

Put this on your `.right-nav`

Display `flex` is very useful for this kind of situations. 
Property `flex-direction` isn't neccesary, display flex itself is `flex-direction: row;` by default.
The `gap` isn't neccesary too, it just makes a gap between your items. 
`align-items` is to align your items vertically in the center.

```
.right-nav {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   gap: 10px;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: a [repro] would greatly increase the value of your answer. It validates by a working example that your answer would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to go about creating this display, but probably the most straightforward approach in modern CSS is to use **CSS Flexbox**.

(Or, in this case, *two nested Flexboxes*.)

The example below has two elements which use:

```
display: flex;
```

One is the `<header>` itself, which means its two immediate children:

- `<h2 class="logo-style">`
- `<nav>`

will be flexibly positioned along its horizontal axis.

The other is the `<nav>`, which means its two immediate children:

- `<ul>`
- `<a class="menu">`

will in turn *also* be flexibly positioned along its own horizontal axis.

Note that the `<header>` has a `justify-content` value of `space-between` which means that the first of its two children will be positioned towards the left and the second will be positioned towards the right.

By contrast, the `<nav>` has a `justify-content` value of `flex-end` which means that both of its children will be positioned towards the right.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo-style a {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 39px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: #4C5BA0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 18px;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #4C5BA0;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 27px;
  background: linear-gradient(brown 0% 20%, white 20% 40%, brown 40% 60%, white 60% 80%, brown 80% 100%);
}

.menu:hover {
  height: 27px;
  background: linear-gradient(black 0% 20%, white 20% 40%, black 40% 60%, white 60% 80%, black 80% 100%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2 class="logo-style"><a href="#news">Web title</a></h2>

  <nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#archives">Archives</a></li>
     <li><a href="#coverage">Coverage</a></li>
   </ul>
   
   <a href="#menu" class="menu"></a>
  </nav>

</header>
```